# Mocking request data in aiohttp

Tags: python, unit-testing, aiohttp

I was reading the docs on passing global like variable through functions in aiohttp: http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web.html#data-sharing-aka-no-singletons-please 
The best solution for me at this point is storing the value in the Request instance. 
That leads me to my other problem: When testing the code I want to be able to mock the value that gets into the request in order for it to be used in a function:

Concrete implementation:

```
async def bar(req)
    req['my_key'] = 1
async def foo(req)
    variable = req['my_key']
    if variable == whatever:
        do stuff
```

Unit Test code:

```
@patch('xxx.yyy.bar',side_effect=mock_bar) # mock_bar returns true/false
@patch('xxx.yyy.foo.req["my_key"]', return_value=1)
def test_that_calls_route_that_calls_bar_and_foo():
    #test fails because the concrete condition doesn't know who req["my_key"] is
```

I have also tried to make a mocked Request with make_mocked_request like shown here: http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/testing.html#aiohttp.test_utils.make_mocked_request
but I was not able to set the needed key

Comment: `xxx.yyy.foo.req["my_key"]` is not an object you can mock. Mock whatever is passed into `foo()` instead. How is `foo()` called?

Comment: The unit test calls a route, that calls ends into the corresponding function that calls both foo and bar.

Comment: So show how `foo` and `bar` are called so we can see how to mock the objects passed in.

Comment: But if this is a unittest, why not just mock `foo()` and `bar()` *themselves* instead of only the object passed in? Focus on one single unit, you seem to have an integration test here.

Comment: Yeah, we want to see the real results of foo at this point.

Comment: You can still unittest `foo()` directly and mock `foo()` for testing the caller..

Comment: I guess it's the best solution we can go for right now. Thanks!